# Spotify can't be restarted from Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, spotify

I'm listening to Spotify with a BT headset, and once I remove the headset from my ears, it pauses the playback automatically. After a couple of hours, Spotify disappears from available players, and if I put the headphones back, it can't restart the playback.

When Spotify goes inactive, I got this in logcat:

```
AvrcpMediaPlayerList: onActiveSessionsChanged: number of controllers: 1
```

Note: I have another player so in case there is also Spotify, it should be 2.

I have to unlock the phone and start the playback manually.

Is this a bug? Has anyone found any solution?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Bluetooth AVRCP and multiple media players, but an app might have been killed by the system if it's not active/used for a couple of hours to preserve the memory. So, it's still unclear if it's a bug or expected.

Comment: I have turned off all battery optimizations, but thats likely the case. Although my phone has more then 10GB RAM :D